# javascript syntax error setting property of jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jquery data table like this:

```
$.fn.tkDataTable = function(){
        "order": [[ 7, 'asc' ]]

        if (! this.length) return;

        if (typeof $.fn.dataTable != 'undefined') {

            this.dataTable();

        }

    };
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I get this on the line with "order".  How can I correctly set this attribute without the syntax error?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This looks like a new function rather than a function call to set up a datatable.

Comment: do `if($.fn.dataTable) ` instead of `if (typeof $.fn.dataTable != 'undefined')`, because : undefined, null, 0 are "rendered" as false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rarely call datatable without an options object

I suspect what you want is something like

```
$.fn.tkDataTable = function(){
    var opts = {
       "order": [[ 7, 'asc' ]],
       //...  other initialization properties
    };

    if (! this.length) return;

    if (typeof $.fn.dataTable != 'undefined') {
        // pass options to plugin
        this.dataTable(opts);

    }
}
```

Comment: with this line of code (typeof $.fn.dataTable != 'undefined') are you checking whether datatable exist before adding options.  If so, is it necessary to add that line If I am sure that datatable exists in the page....